# getElementById gives result plus strings

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to extract a div from another website using the following code:

```
<?php

    $doc = new DomDocument;

     //We need to validate our document before refering to the id
    $doc->validateOnParse = true;
    $doc->loadHtml(file_get_contents('http://myaddresshere'));

    var_dump($doc->getElementById('the div'));



?>
```

I can get the result but i am also getting a long php code string before that:

```
object(DOMElement)#2 (18) { ["tagName"]=> string(2) "h3" ["schemaTypeInfo"]=> NULL ["nodeName"]=> string(2) "h3" ["nodeValue"]=> string(35) "Telephone Technical Support: Active" ["nodeType"]=> int(1) ["parentNode"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" ["childNodes"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" ["firstChild"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" ["lastChild"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" ["previousSibling"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" ["nextSibling"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" ["attributes"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" ["ownerDocument"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" ["namespaceURI"]=> NULL ["prefix"]=> string(0) "" ["localName"]=> string(2) "h3" ["baseURI"]=> NULL ["textContent"]=> string(35) ***"Telephone Technical Support: Active"*** }
```

How can i remove all that string and only get the div's content.

- The div in question show's a Boolean result (Active/Expired)

Comment: You realize that that's an object, not a string? Just get the `nodeValue` property. I'm not entirely sure of the syntax but I think it's `$the_div = $doc->getElementById(id); $the_div->nodeValue`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the value of a node in two ways:

```
DomElement->nodeValue; // inherited from DomNode
```

Or via

```
<?php 
function get_inner_html( $node ) { 
    $innerHTML= ''; 
    $children = $node->childNodes; 
    foreach ($children as $child) { 
        $innerHTML .= $child->ownerDocument->saveXML( $child ); 
    } 

    return $innerHTML; 
} 
?>
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php for more information.